# How to access control on current TabbedPage?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a tabbed page with a stacklayout that I populate with some child controls. The page originally had no navigation but now I've added the tabbed page (created programmatically in the app.cs) it means that the method below is unable to populate the selected tabbed page's stacklayout.

I need to know how to access the current tabbed page and then add the items to the stacklayout.

```
public static void addToReadout(string name, string time, string inout)
{
    try
    {
        Label label1 = new Label { Text = name + " Successfully clocked " + inout + " @ " + time, TextColor = Color.Black };
        StackLayout sl = new StackLayout();


        var mp = (MainPage)App.Current.MainPage;


        if (mp.readOut.Children.Count() < 7)
        {

            mp.readOut.Children.Add(label1);
            mp.readOut.Children.Count();
        }
        else
        {
            mp.readOut.Children.RemoveAt(0);
            mp.readOut.Children.Add(label1);
            mp.readOut.Children.Count();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        ErrorRepository.InsertError(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

This issue is with this row since changing to a tabbed page setup:

```
var mp = (MainPage)App.Current.MainPage;
```

Answer (score -1):

TabbedPage has a [CurrentPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.MultiPage%3CT%3E.CurrentPage/) property that will return a reference to the current active page.

If your MainPage inherits from TabbedPage, you can do this

```
var mp = (MainPage)App.Current.MainPage;
var current = mp.CurrentPage;
```

Edit: based on the code you pasted in the comments

```
var mp = (TabbedPage)App.Current.MainPage;
var main = mp.CurrentPage;
```

Comment: I tried this by inheriting the TabbedPage but now on the first line it says Cannot convert and the second line says there's no definition for 'CurrentPage'

Comment: in your App.cs (or App.xaml.cs) when you assign MainPage, that will be the class that Current.MainPage points to.  Does that class inherit from TabbedPage?

Comment: This is what it looks like:                     MainPage = new TabbedPage { Children = { new MainPage(), new CompanySetup{ BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("baf4d5") }, new ChangePassword { BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("baf4d5") } } };

Comment: With your edit it's saying there's no definition for 'readout' (the stacklayout).

Comment: have you verified that what it's returning is actually an instance of your MainPage class?